# i have bulk csv file i want to read it in dictionary then write the dictionary again into new csv file ,

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

> i have the below lines in bulk csv file: 
>   date, id, site, linkup,linkdwon , count, connection
>
> 20190102,100000000204197,google.com,1,2,1,5
>
> 20190102,100000000204197,yahoo.com,2,2,1,5
>
> 20190102,100000000204197,yahoo.com,1,2,2,3
>
> 20190102,41602323232,google.com,4,11,3
>
> 20190102,41602323232,google.com,1,3,1,7
>
> based on id and site i want agregate them
>
> 100000000204197,google.com,1,2,1,5
>
> 100000000204197,yahoo.com,3,4,3,8
>
> 20190102,41602323232,google.com,5,4,2,10

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import Counter
import csv
with open('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/Tareq-Qassrawi/report.txt','r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf)
    with open ('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/Tareq-Qassrawi/writer.txt','w') as wf:
        hashing_table = {}
        connection_val= 0
        connection_val_2=0
        for line in reader:
            key = int(line[1])
            if key != hashing_table.items():
                hashing_table =({'IMSI':key
                ,'SITE':str(line[2])
                ,'DATE':str(line[0])
                ,'linkup' :int(line[3])
                ,'linkdown':int(line[4])
                ,'count':int(line[5])
                ,'connection':int(line[6])
                    })
                connection_val = connection_val + int(hashing_table.get('connection'))
                hashing _table[key].update({'connection':connection_val})
            else:
                connection_val_2 = connection_val_2 + int(hashing_table.get('connection'))
                hashing _table[key].update({'connection':connection_val2})
```

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Odeh, Welcome to SO.  Can you please name your columns in your data sample, and be explicit about what you are trying to add (which columns)?  For example, show the input, then the expected output.  This to me looks like you would read the whole dict with from_csv, then do a groupby

Comment: @ivan7707 i edit the main question , can you help me sir:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

Using the amazing pandas module by http://wesmckinney.com/ (and a whole host of open source # contributors now.  see Docs here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv') # read in your data from the csv file.  
df.groupby(['id', 'site']).sum() # groupby here groups your data by both the id and sum.
```

[image]

To get the id to show for all of them instead of omitting the repeated, we use reset_index

```
df.groupby(['id', 'site']).sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

If you are using data a lot in your life/career, look into jupyter notebook or jupyter lab as well:  https://jupyter.org/

Good luck and welcome to SO and python open source data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas' [`from_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for this purpose.